# Classpath in Dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I would like to ask you for your help with dockerizing cucumber java project.

I need to add parameter classpath for maven library to dockerfile. Maven lib is stored in my project as external lib.

but I have to add this maven jar into classpath in docker container. Because I need to run command java cp with class store in maven jar as I mentioned above.

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't you just use a base image that already has maven installed? Like one of these : https://hub.docker.com/_/maven ? Then you just have an `mvn` command/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunaly I cannot. I have to avoid using mvn command because I will use this docker project in Jenkins node without maven.
I need to replace e.g. /Users/lenovo/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-core/1.2.5/cucumber-core-1.2.5.jar with classpath of storage 
maven cucumber lib in docker container.

Comment: But if you use a container that already has maven installed, it doesn't matter whether your host (jenkins) has it installed or not. It's just gonna do a `docker run` with your image, and that'll just run your `CMD`, which will consist of some form of an `mvn` command.

Comment: This point I did not know. So I will use mvn command.in RUN command in Dockerfile.Thank you.